# Change bounce background pageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building an app including `pageViewController` and defining the inside controllers as following..etc, whiteout adding subviews.

```
storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
```

I can't find property to change the background of pageViewController bounce from black for example to white, is it really possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just worked for me by setting the background colour inside `UIPageViewController` `viewDidLoad` method, then it changed the background including bounce :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```